# Hibernate, query does not retrieve related entities

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, java-ee-7

I got a question about querying.

```
public Event queryEventById(long tmpId) {
    EntityManager manager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
    return (Event) manager.createQuery("SELECT e FROM Event e WHERE e.id = :id")
            .setParameter("id", tmpId).getSingleResult();
}
```

This works but i got one problem. Event has a Set (container) of the entity Organizer which is a join table for Events and Users.
However the event created with this query leaves the Set with organizers empty.

When persisting lets say Events to the database everything works great but not when retrieving.

In events i retrieve organizers like this.

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "event",cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
public Set<Organizer> getOrganizers() {
    return this.organizers;
}
```

Organizer entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ORGANIZERS")
public class Organizer implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private long id;
    private User user;
    private Event event;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "ORGANIZER_ID")
    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public Organizer() {

    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "USER_ID")  
    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "EVENT_ID")
    public Event getEvent() {
        return event;
    }

    public void setEvent(Event event) {
        this.event = event;
    }
}
```

Any suggestions ?

Okey this have been kinda frustrating but i finally found the problem.

```
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "event",cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
public Set<Organizer> getOrganizers() {
    return this.organizers;
}
```

the mappedBy was set to organizer instead of event.

Comment: Can you show us `Organizer` entity?

Comment: Updated main post

Comment: Must be something wrong with the organizer or event entity cuz the event got other collection of enteties also that does fetch.

Comment: When you're fetching an entity by it's id, why not just use `manager.find(Event.class, id)`? That way it doesn't blow-up on you if there is no result. It just returns a null. Also creating a new entity manager for each function is a bad idea. Use a thread-local entity manager or just pass one to all the functions until the processing is done, and make sure you always close them. You have an unclosed entity manager now.

Comment: Thanks for the advices @coladict . I have updated the main post. Was a mapping problem. About the entityManager you are absolutely right. I will fix this also :)